# Unable to set selected attribute after page loads

Tags: javascript, dom

My html page with SELECT and OPTIONS values sets one of the options as a default.

Were the user to choose a different option, which then takes him to a new page, I’d like to preserve that value so the next time home page is generated the value the user selected should remain on display, rather than the original default value, when the window reloads.

How do I do this in javascript?

I had tried to save values via a DOM capture of the selected value, but I don’t seem to be able to change that original default value.

E.g.,, one line of code reads:

```
window.location.reload();
```

yet were I to use “hold values” to capture the user’s selected option that differs from the default option, like so:

```
var holdPick = document.getElementById(“uPick”).value;
window.location.reload();
document.getElementById(“uPick”).value = holdPick;
```

that won’t do the trick, and I know not why.

Comment: Are you using the `“ ”` as double quote?

Comment: The usual quotation mark("), not two of these (').

Comment: I was asking, are you using `“ ”`, or are you using `" "`.

Comment: The file saves as UTF-8

Comment: Why do you ask, Leo?

Answer (score 0):

When you reload a page, all the JavaScript is reloaded too. So, that's why the JavaScript snippet you posted doesn't seem to be working... The line after `window.location.reload();` isn't even run at all. If you want to have a value that persists between page loads, you'll need to set and retrieve a cookie. Check out the JavaScript `document.cookie` API at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.cookie). That should tell you what you need to know about storing and retrieving your value in a cookie.

Comment: But if I need to set the selected option after the page loads, where does that code go if that which follows this line of code (window.location.reload();) is where it ought to be?

Comment: You run the code on page load. So, you attach an event handler to window.onload, and there pull out the value from your cookie, if it exists, and use it to set the option that is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Why: every time `var holdPick` is executed it will create variable from scratch.
Second line tells the browser to reload page, so the third line never gets the chance to be executed.

I'd recommend usage of [HTML5 Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

```
if (sessionStorage.uPick) { //check if variable has been set already
    document.getElementById(“uPick”).value  = sessionStorage.uPick;
} else {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = document.getElementById(“uPick”).value;
}
```

you can use [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) also, but I don't think it is as straight forward.

Comment: But if I need to set the selected option after the page loads, where does that code go if that which follows this line of code (window.location.reload();) is where it ought to be?

Comment: Thanks a lot jpfreire.

Comment: You can use `window.onload` or  `$(document).ready()` from jQuery. I'd recommend the later.